# extending xorg.conf to account for a boot from virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-10.10, xorg.conf

i have a ubuntu10.10/win7 dual boot. i use win7 as a host for virtual box and run the existing ubuntu in virtual box.

when i installed vb additions and extensions, the xorg.conf file got overwritten.

depending on how i would boot (natively or through virtual machine) i have to change xorg.conf file manually. is there a way to make it automatic? putting both configs into xorg.conf file didn't work.

i filed a ticket couple days ago http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8360 but got no response. i'm sure there is a quick fix for this. any ideas??? i documented my experience (if u need more details) here: http://kirilligum.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/run-existing-linux-ubuntu-10-10-partition-in-virtualbox-under-host-windows-7-system-on-thinkpad-x201t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a script in /etc/init.d that runs during boot that detects whether or not it's running in a VirtualBox VM, and install the appropriate xorg.conf.  Something similar to this should work:

```
if [ `dmidecode -s system-product-name` = "VirtualBox" ]
then
    cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.vbox /etc/X11/xorg.conf
else
    cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.real /etc/X11/xorg.conf
fi
```

Comment: i've made a .sh file with the script that you wrote, made it executable and put it into /etc/init.d/   it doesn't start on reboot. how do i make it start on startup?

Comment: That technique works for me on Fedora, but perhaps Ubuntu does it differently.  Try calling your script from within /etc/rc.local.  That file is supposed to run each time Ubuntu boots.

Comment: i just have to put the script in the folder and make it executable, right?

Comment: That's all you should need to do in /etc/init.d.  But if that's not working, edit /etc/rc.local and call your script from there.

Comment: turns out i just needed to do update-rc.d vbstart.sh default    , thank you!